# Sound Waves and Random Walks

Tags: waves, acoustics

Is it possible to explain/study sound waves using random walks? If yes, how will you do it. This question is related to me reading somewhere that woodwind instruments are possible in 3 dimensional world, but not in 2 dimensional world, and this can be explained using random walks.

Comment: For anyone asking for the source, here is: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/walks/walks.pdf (Paragraph 2 of Preface)